# Can't change ESlint eqeqeq option to "smart"

Tags: javascript, eslint

There is errors in my code:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error eqeqeq  (ESLint) Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='.

I can't find where to disable ONLY the `eqeqeq` option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your ESLint config?

Comment: I have no config eslint in my project. The error started after update of Visual Studio

Comment: Then I guess you have to figure out where Visual Studio is getting the config from.

Comment: Thanks @vlaz, but  I need to change this option in generally, not in my local config file Or maybe we can supress some warning like it is done in .net framework where in project properties you can add suppress warnings

Comment: Hence why I said you have to find where the config for VS is. So you can modify that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**To turn off the eqeqeq rule everywhere:**

1. Open Windows Explorer with Windows Key + E
2. Paste exactly this into your URL bar:  `%USERPROFILE%` and hit Enter
3. Find the file `.eslintrc`
4. Right-click
5. `open with...`, Notepad (or your favorite text editor)
6. Find:

> ```
> "rules": {
>     "eqeqeq": "always",
> ```

and change it to "off" to disable, or "smart" (see below):

> ```
> "rules": {
>     "eqeqeq": "off",
> ```

---

> smart
>
> The "smart" option enforces the use of === and !== except for these
>   cases:
>
> ```
> Comparing two literal values
> Evaluating the value of typeof
> Comparing against null
> ```

7. Then, Restart Visual Studio for it to take effect.

Link for more information:

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/eqeqeq

---

**To turn off the eqeqeq rule on a *per file basis***, paste this at the top of your .js file:

`/*eslint eqeqeq: "off"*/`

---

**To turn off the *all ESLint functionality* on a per-project basis**, create a file named `.eslintrc.json` in your project's root folder, (or any folder you want ESLint turned off), with the following contents:

`{ }`

Comment: Thanks for help, it partially works for me the only problem is .. you can't ignore eslint for specific project, It will be good that I can ignore this option only on specific js file or for specific project.

Comment: You might find more information here:  https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

Comment: Actually, I managed to turn off eslint in a Visual Studio Project by adding  a `.eslintrc.json` file that simply has `{ }` in it, and it turned off ESLint in my project!

Comment: The comment in the file should look like this, I just tested it: `/*eslint eqeqeq: "off"*/`

Comment: Thanks SeanKendle, It is really what I want.